# Looking for best practice to handle conditional logic inside controller actions in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, custom-action-filter

Currently I am looking for best practice in handling conditions inside the controller actions in asp.net mvc. For example -

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id = 0)
{
   var Item = _todoListItemsRepository.Find(Id);
   **if (Item == null)
      return View("NotFound");
   if (!Item.IsAuthorized())
      return View("NotValidOwner");**

   return View("Edit", Item);
}
```

The above two conditions marked in bold is used in other actions inside the controller. So, in order not to repeat these conditions in all the actions. I have used the below approach.

```
[HttpGet]       
[Authorize]
[ModelStatusActionFilter]
public ActionResult Edit(int Id = 0)
{
    var Item = _todoListItemsRepository.Find(Id);        
    return View("Edit", Item);
}


public class ModelStatusActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ITodoListItemsRepository _todoListItemsRepository;
    public ModelStatusActionFilterAttribute()
        : this(new TodoListItemsRepository())
    {

    }
    public ModelStatusActionFilterAttribute(ITodoListItemsRepository     todoListItemsRepository)
    {
        _todoListItemsRepository = todoListItemsRepository;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var Id = Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.RouteData.Values["Id"]);
            var Item = _todoListItemsRepository.Find(Id);
            if (Item == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewName = "NotFound" };
            }
            else if (!Item.IsAuthorized())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewName = "NotValidOwner" };
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }                
}
```

I am unsure if this is the best practice in handling such scenarios. So, could someone please advise ?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Can someone please reply to my question ?

Comment: if your code is working as intended and not causing errors then this is not exactly the right site in the network for your question.  You might try Code Review.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually you don't use action filter for so-called business logic of your web application - this is what the controllers are for. Action filter are rather for the whole stuff which is external to the actual logic - common case is logging, performance measurement, checking if user is authenticated / authorized (I don't think this is your case, although you call IsAuthorized method on the "Item").

Reducing code is generally good thing but in this case, I don't think putting the logic to action is a good way, because you;ve actually made it a bit unreadable, and unreadable code is in my opinon much worse than repeated code.
Also, specifically in your case, for all valid items you actually call the _todoListItemsRepository.Find() twice (for each valid item), which might be costly if this is some webservice call or db lookup.

If the code is just repeated throughout the actions, make a method out of it like:

```
private View ValidateItem(Item) {
    if (Item == null)
      return View("NotFound");
   if (!Item.IsAuthorized())
      return View("NotValidOwner");
return null; }
```